# PHP 8.1 for linux lux nebula?

Tags: php, linux

I'm trying to install php version 8.1 through the terminal but I'm not succeeding, the distribution I'm using is only downloading version 7.4. My only hope would be to switch operating systems. Can anybody help me?

The commands I used

```
  $ sudo apt update
  $ sudo apt -y upgrade
  $ sudo apt install -y lsb-release ca-certificates apt-transport-https software-properties-common
  $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
  $ sudo apt update
  $ sudo apt install php8.1
```

The distribution:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Lux
Description:    Lux 0 (nebula)
Release:    0
Codename:   nebula
Linux fernanda 6.1.4-lux-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Feb  6 16:51:49 -03 2023 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Using the commands, result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDysj.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), it makes it so much harder to read, search, and copy.

Comment: I can't find any information about "Lux", but one of the error messages in your screenshot mentions "mantic", which is the codename of the as-yet-unreleased Ubuntu 23.10 ("Mantic Minotaur"). The [PPA you tried to use](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php) only supports active "LTS" releases of Ubuntu - that's currently 20.04 ("Focal Fossa") and 22.04 ("Jammy Jellyfish")